# Pug создание частей html

Tags: html, node.js, gulp, jade, pug

В сборщике можно подключить  множество *.pug файлов, которые будут создавать один index.html. Что нужно написать, чтобы создавались html файлы с таким же названием и содержимым, как и в файле *.pug

Например:

header.pug -> header.html

menu.pug -> menu.html

В идеале, чтобы создавались отдельные файлы и один общий файл index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создать директорию к примеру - app с нужными вам файлами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скомпилированные Галпом html файлы отправляются в папку - public повторяя структуру созданную ранее в папке - app

**1** в консоли в которой запускаете gulp набрать:

  npm init --yes

появиться файл - package.json

**2** создать файл - gulpfile.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**3** - установка gulp в проект c папкой - app

  npm i gulp --save

**4** - установка pug компилятора в проект c папкой - app

  npm i gulp-pug --save

**5** - в созданный файл - gulpfile.js копируем ниже представленный код:

для подключения установленных пакетов - gulp, gulp-pug

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    pug = require('gulp-pug');

gulp.task('pug', function buildHTML() {
  return gulp.src('app/pug/**/*.pug')

    .pipe(pug({
      pretty: true
    }))

    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/'))
});
```

**5** для запуска компиляции pug, в консоли набрать - gulp pug